# Can Selenium RC tests written in Python be integrated into PHPUnit?

Tags: python, selenium, phpunit

I'm working on large project in PHP and I'm running phpundercontrol with PHPUnit for my unit tests. I would like to use Selenium RC for running acceptance tests.  Unfortunately the only person I have left to write tests only knows Python.  Can Selenium tests written in Python be integrated into PHPUnit?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with integration? Do you need a similar output from your tests? Do you need to trigger your python tests from php? Do you need your python tests to trigger php code?

Comment: I would need PHPUnit to execute the python tests, and then report back on the success or failure.  I believe PHPUnit can do this with selenium tests written in PHP, I'm wondering if this is also possible with Selenium tests written in python.

Comment: Any chance of using the Selenium IDE? It handles exporting to myriad of languages, and also, PHPUnit can run Selenese directly, making running & debugging tests faster. See PHPUnit's docs on running selenese directly here: http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/selenium.html#selenium.seleniumtestcase.examples.WebTest4.php

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that comes to my mind is running them through the shell.
It would be:

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('python testScript.py');
echo $output;
?>
```

It's not too integrated with phpunit, but once you get the output in a variable ($output), you can then parse the text inside it to see if you have "E" or "." ("E" states for errors in pyunit and "." states for pass).

This is the best thing I could think of, hope it helps.